# Python: Add Submenu

Tags: python

I am creating a simple add-on in Blender. Initially I tested the code in Python console, then I wrapped it in an operator and added it to **Object** menu, it worked well:

```
class MyOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'object.MyOperator'
    bl_label = 'MyOperator'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        # ...affairs...
        return {'FINISHED'}


def task_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(MyOperator.bl_idname)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(task_func)
```

But now I need to add several operators and a submenu. I tried [this example](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.Menu.html#submenus), and but it is not working:

```
class MyMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_idname = 'object.MyMenu'
    bl_label = 'MyMenu'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator(MyMenu.bl_idname, text=MyMenu.bl_label)


def menu_func(self, context):
    # None of these is working :(
    self.layout.call_menu(name=MyMenu.bl_idname)
    self.layout.menu(MyMenu.bl_idname)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)
```

So, what's the problem about? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were a number of issues. From not registering menu class and having invalid `bl_idname`'s (no capital letters)

Here is working code.  In 2.8 it is a requirement that class names reflect the `bl_idname`.

```
import bpy

class OBJECT_OT_myoperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'object.myoperator'
    bl_label = 'MyOperator'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        # ...affairs...
        return {'FINISHED'}

class OBJECT_MT_mymenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_idname = 'object.mymenu'
    bl_label = 'MyMenu'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator(OBJECT_OT_myoperator.bl_idname)

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.menu(OBJECT_MT_mymenu.bl_idname)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_myoperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_MT_mymenu)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_myooperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_MT_mymenu)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```